# Drupal 7 completely offline, avoid Boostrap via CDN

Tags: 7, bootstrapping, cdn

I need to move my Drupal site to completely offline environment.
 The bootstrap library takes the correct Bootstrap JS and CSS from sites/all/libraries, but there is a CDN call to download Bootstrap that screws up the bootstrap functions (ex: popup is undefined) in other JS.

So, I have all necessary JS files locally, they are correctly loaded but when I switch off internet, bootstrap functions are undefined.

As far as I see in Bootstrap module, there is no way to avoid this CDN call. I setup in boostrap module settings[bootstrap_cdn] = 0  but it's still calling.

Would appreciate a lot any idea, its kind of urgent.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Bootstrap Library module](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap_library)